# Can we edit the dont-ask section of Help?

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I've just looked at the help center's [don't ask](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page, and it doesn't seem quite right for this site:

> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: "What if ______ happened?"

**Almost all** our questions here are this in some form or another: *what if* everyone had horses, *what if* I could scale down the Solar System... you get the point.

It might be an idea to reconsider the text on this page. I assume it's an SE-wide standard text (though I haven't checked), but it seems it doesn't quite apply to every site.

Can we change this?

Comment: I say let's change it.

Comment: Also inappropriate: _"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."_

Answer (score 3):

First off, yes, it does appear that **the page in question is not editable by moderators.**

That said, **I'm not so sure that phrasing is necessarily a problem** in practice, even if people were to take it more literally. Notice that the bullet point specifically talks about *open-ended* questions. That's basically what we call [idea generation](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/552/29) questions: every answer is equally valid, and there is little or no way to judge how well each answer actually answers the question. *That* is what the bullet point aims to discourage ([not even disallow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), a blog post which I strongly encourage everyone here to read; also, hence the heading "*avoid* asking ...").

Keep in mind what we say on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (my emphasis):

> Note that **questions must be [specific](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [answerable](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).** If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific question-and-answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't seem to have access to edit this page, so our options are limited unless Stack Exchange want to add this as a feature.

I agree that particular line is unfortunate but most of the page is reasonably well suited to our needs.

Comment: It's just that if everyone took that page literally we'd have no site. I've tagged this a feature request so someone from SE should notice...

Answer (score 1):

The [Ask Patents Help Center](//patents.stackexchange.com/help), for example, has content that is different from the usual boilerplate.

However, most of the Help Center pages are not editable by users or moderators.  What Code Review has done is [draft the pages on Meta](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5086/9357).  When ready, you can ask a Community Manager to publish the draft.