# What makes this NOT idea generation question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

See this question: [An exotic yet portable powersource](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11384/an-exotic-yet-portable-powersource)

I love it. I totally LOVE it, but...

Isn't it idea generation question? And if not, what makes it **not** idea generation?

Comment: I am not entirely sure why but I am inclined to allow this question even though I agree it *feels* like idea generation.  Maybe its that it is science based and we aren't all experts.  I also feel that answers will be reusable by other people.

Answer (score 4):

[What's wrong with "idea generation" questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/522/whats-wrong-with-idea-generation-questions)

> - There are too many possible answers to the question (Idea Generation is a subset of Too Broad)
> - There is no objective way to evaluate one idea as better than others
>
> A common symptom is that answers will tend to list a number of different possibilities rather than expanding on one. This is a consequence of the first problem, as the person posting the response has no way to know which of their ideas are better.

This is science-based, asking for something specific (portable powerful energy sources), answers can be rated based on reasonableness, plausibility, and appropriateness.

I agree it's on the edge but in my opinion it has got a sufficiently constrained answer set to make it workable, and as a result no-one has seen fit to close it.

Comment: First I wanted to post my close vote, but my inner editor told me not to. But I wanted to make clear why is it so. And I agree, it is quite on edge to me too, but answerable. Thanks for your opinion