# Is the Inaccurate Map question still off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I'm working on narrowing down [How to go about creating an "inaccurate" map?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/18730/2138) to be a better question.

I think my most recent edits help, but is it enough?

If not, any further ideas of what I would need to clarify in order to narrow it down further?

Answer (score 3):

Your question was closed on the basis that it was an Idea Generation question (given a 3/2 split for IG/straight off-topic - I hit the wrong one when voting). This means:

- There are many valid answers;
- It is hard or impossible to *objectively* judge which is best.

The close reason reflects this:

> Questions about Idea Generation are off-topic because they tend to result in list answers with no objective means to compare the quality of one answer with the others.

See also: [What's wrong with "idea generation" questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/522/whats-wrong-with-idea-generation-questions)

Thus, to improve it you should add some way of objectively judging answers. A question here *can be* idea generation, *if* it is possible to judge it. By far the easiest way to demonstrate this is to say "I will pick the best answer based on X, Y, and Z criteria". Perhaps in your case, you could judge the best answer to be the method that is *most wrong* and *least obvious* to inhabitants.

Your recent edits *do* help with this, they just didn't go quite far enough.

---

The other close reason given was off-topic, as in

> This question does not appear to be about worldbuilding, within the scope defined in the help center

Personally, I don't see how this is off-topic here - but if it is, there's very little that can be done to remedy the question while keeping the same basic question - it would have to be moved to another site where it is on topic. I don't think you need to worry about this one.

Comment: That is a good way to phrase the criteria - I'm going to pretty much steal it word-for-word ;)

Comment: @DoubleDouble go ahead, I wrote it with that possibility in mind...

Comment: @ArtOfCode re: why it was "off-topic"--I don't have enough rep to vote here, but I flagged it off-topic because I thought it seemed more about the character himself or character-building, which is expressly off-topic according to the Help Center. Someone else clarified an alternate interpretation by which the question wasn't about the cartographer but it still wasn't clear to me what was meant by "meaningful" or what would constitute a good answer. I think the recent edits help.

Comment: @rob - thanks for the clarification. If the recent edits help then the question looks OK for now.

Comment: @rob Asking "how can my character achieve X?" seeking *methods to achieve a goal* isn't necessarily off topic (it depends heavily on the specifics of X), but it *may* be idea-generation or simply too broad. Character-building is more along the lines of asking "would my character be able to do X?" or "how would my character react to X?", and that type of questions are off topic because (a) they are almost certainly not useful to anyone but yourself, and (b) they depend completely on the specifics of that particular character, which the character owner is supposed to be the final authority on.

Comment: That said, good call on flagging. It's better to flag once too much than once too little, in case you are uncertain. (I recommend going back through your profile to check how the flag ended up being treated by the community; doing so will help you learn what to flag and what doesn't need to be flagged.) Flagging gets the post into the review queues, where the more experienced members of our community can take a look at it and judge how they feel about it.