# Idea Generation in Help

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We usually agree that idea generation questions should be avoided, as per [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/522/whats-wrong-with-idea-generation-questions). However I had the feeling that we used to have a more explicit statement about it in the help section.... but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Was it removed? Is so, why? Is my impression wrong and there never was such notice? If so, why shouldn't we?

Idea generation is a common reason for closing down questions, and a typical mistake made here. Shouldn't we dedicate a few lines in the help?

Comment: When you VTC, you can choose between *Too Broad* or *Off-Topic...* because *Idea Generation*. But if we had some help section about it, it might prevent some new posters to have IG questions...

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic does say "Note that questions must be specific as well as answerable.", but I'm not sure there's anything much closer to what you are looking for than that in the help center proper.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, yes and the "open ended" part in the questions to be avoided also go in that direction. But effectively, comments refer to the terms "idea generation" as well as the closing vote. But those terms are missing form the help. And I am not sure new comers peruse meta posts BEFORE posting their first question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the "Idea Generation" close option, because I think that's what this entire site is about.

I'd prefer to just have "Too Broad" and a second option of "Too Subjective".  I think that second one covers most "bad" Idea Generation categories while being more accurate.

Comment: I think idea generation might be the wrong name for the reason. It might be worth starting a discussion on renaming it...