# A Proposal to End the Love/Hate Relationship with Brainstorming, AKA List questions, Idea-Generation, and Fishing-for-Ideas

Tags: discussion, policy, question-types, rules-exception

### Preliminary Information

Before I begin, I want to make a clear distinction insofar as I understand the principal purpose of this Stack (the following closely fits the rules as defined in the Tour and the Help Center, but may not be universally agreed upon by the community):

**Worldbuilding** (on-topic) is the development and consistent use of rules, designs, definitions, and explanations that identify or express an imaginary world of the querent's own creation wherein any number of stories may be told, but which are independent of any story that can be told.

**Storybuilding** (off-topic) is the creation of a story, no matter how well integrated with its world. It includes plot; circumstances; character & organization choices, decisions, options, and actions; and impossible-to-fit-within-SE's-rules aesthetics such as names, language evolution, the influence of culture, species or environment on design, etc.

I'm making this distinction to help clearly define the purpose of this discussion and vote. *This is only about worldbuilding.* At this time, all storybuilding is *off-topic.* **Therefore, a choice to adopt a policy to accept brainstorming questions is NOT approval to accept storybuilding questions.** From the [on-topic Help Center page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, **not to tell your story.**
>
> If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site.

### Why am I Asking for This Vote?

This Stack has had a long and complicated relationship with a fundamental and arguably necessary tool of worldbuilding: Brainstorming. Indeed, [one of my own earliest answers](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/94749/40609), and still the answer I'm most fond of, is an answer to a brainstorming question. Although (and if I remember correctly) the statement in the Help Center warning against brainstorming didn't exist back then, all of the Tour and Help Center rules reflected by that statement did.

Brainstorming questions *always* violate the basic operational model of Stack Exchange: one-specific-question/one-best-answer. Many, if not most, of the non-community rules found in the Tour and the Help Center are influenced by, if not directly supporting of, that premise. It isn't up for debate because it belongs to Stack Exchange, not us. Therefore (and not surprisingly) [the first question about the viability of brainstorming questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/522/40609) occurred a scant two months after the miraculous graduation of Worldbuilding.SE from Area 51.

*Two months!* And we've been debating it ever since... for the last eight years.<sup>1</sup> The current manifestation of the brainstorming rule is a non-committal non-rule that makes everyone tear their hair out. Neither allowing brainstorming, nor prohibiting brainstorming, [it says](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question.

Members of the WB.SE community, I suspect that whether you want to see brainstorming questions or not, you will all agree that the current state of affairs is unacceptable.

**The purpose of this post is to affect a change to the Help Center's "On Topic" page.** However, that can only be done by the moderators. We're at their mercy. However, if a solid consensus is achieved, at the very least we can point to this post as authorization to act contrary to what the Help Center says.

### Argument: Brainstorming is one of the most common and most popular question types on this Stack

And because brainstorming is so common and popular, it's fundamentally impossible to stop. We've been trying for *eight years* to stop it. It's not working. It won't ever work. Why is obvious:

- Quality worldbuilding involves *dependencies.* While any worldbuilder could sweep away their problem by declaring their rule to be so regardless of those dependencies, it's often the dependencies that add depth and quality to the world.
- Almost none of the querents are sufficiently educated in the topic of their question to adequately understand the dependencies, their consequences, or their benefits. They may not even be capable of identifying the existence of dependencies. All they know is that their rule lacks the depth and quality they've seen in the efforts of others.

A choice to forbid brainstorming questions means rigorously policing all users, including new users, about why the round peg of a naturally creative and imaginative process is being pounded into the square hole of a software platform intentionally designed to be specific, objective, and have a clear "best solution" (from the perspective of a programmer, an answer voted "best practice"). But it's the simplest to defend because the rules are clearly stated.

### Argument: Brainstorming breaks a lot of Stack Exchange's rules

This is the source of the debate. The following list of rules broken by brainstorming is probably not comprehensive. These all come from the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour), the [on-topic Help Center page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the [don't ask Help Center page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and the list of reasons to close a question.<sup>2</sup>

- They are ambiguous (not specific).
- They are too often story-based.
- They are too often an invitation to a discussion.
- They often lack sufficient detail, context, restrictions and requirements to avoid the prohibition against all answers having equal value.
- They can lead to too many answers.
- They are, by definition, open-ended.<sup>3</sup>

A choice to permit brainstorming questions means we are authorizing an exception to any or all of those violations. While a clear update to the Help Center authorizing brainstorming questions would help tremendously, it will not stop the occasional well-meaning user from voting to close a question for violating those rules. However, this choice is likely also easy because only the most anal of people read the Tour and Help Center anyway.

### Argument: The second-to-last paragraph on the on-topic Help Center page might not be within the power of our moderators to modify

While this wouldn't stop a community policy effectively vacating the stated belief about brainstorming, it would mean that adopting a policy to vacate the belief would cause headaches for the next eight years. *It would be a great help if one of the Moderators would post a comment telling us if that paragraph can, or cannot, be modified.* (If it can be modified, but a new paragraph cannot be added, then the new paragraph shown in "UP VOTE" should be appended to the existing paragraph.)

Why is this important? Because policies that can only be found on Meta that don't quickly burn themselves into the community consciousness are quickly forgotten and often difficult to find. It's the weakest form of community policy.

### A Proposal to End the Love/Hate Relationship with Brainstorming (AKA List Questions, Idea-Generation, and Fishing-for-Ideas)

The second-to-last paragraph on the [on-topic Help Center page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) currently reads:

> Questions must be specific as well as answerable. If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question. Such questions may however be welcome in Worldbuilding Chat. Also see Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for why this type of question is hard, and some guidelines on how to post good subjective questions which are less likely to end up being closed.

**UP VOTE:** You advocate for changing this Stack's policy and Help Center page to read as follows, or similar as discussed in answers. Lined out text to be deleted. Bold text to be added.

> Questions must be specific as well as answerable. If you are looking for <s>discussion, brainstorming, or</s> an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question. Such questions may however be welcome in Worldbuilding Chat. Also see Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for why this type of question is hard, and some guidelines on how to post good subjective questions which are less likely to end up being closed.
>
> **Questions seeking a list of possible solutions (also called list questions, brainstorming, idea generation, and fishing for ideas) are permissible only when questions are narrowly scoped by providing details, restrictions and requirements that will lead to a reasonably objective selection of a best answer. Questions deemed to be intentionally written to lead to as many answers as possible will be closed as too broad. Explaining your goals and expectations for answers would be beneficial to avoiding question closure. (Additional details [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10012/40609).)**

**DOWN VOTE:** You advocate for changing this Stack's policy and Help Center page to read as follows, or similar as discussed in answers. Lined out text to be deleted. Bold text to be added.

> Questions must be specific as well as answerable. **Questions seeking a list of possible solutions (also called list questions, brainstorming, idea generation, and fishing for ideas) are prohibited (additional details [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10012/40609)).** If you are looking for <s>discussion, brainstorming, or</s> an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question. Such questions may however be welcome in Worldbuilding Chat. Also see Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for why this type of question is hard, and some guidelines on how to post good subjective questions which are less likely to end up being closed.

*The reader will note I lined out "discussion" as well. Though not specifically related to this post, the word, in the context of that paragraph, contradicts the following statement from the [don't ask Help Center page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), "If your motivation for asking the question is 'I would like to participate in a discussion about ______', then you should not be asking here." I consider that statement to be clear and authoritative compared to the ambiguous statement in the paragraph, above.*

### Details About This Vote

- Comments to this post are for clarifying this post ***only.*** If you wish to voice an opinion or insight about this post, please post an answer so the community can adequately participate in the discussion.
- Proposed changes to wording of either proposal would be appropriate as answers, not comments. Proposed changes will be discussed in comments to the answers and changes made as efficiently as possible.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *I will not take the time to list the dozens — more than dozens! — of questions posted on Meta about brainstorming. If you are unfamiliar with the general problem, reading through a bunch of those posts will give you a flavor for the problem. Please search Meta using the is:q filter and, independently, the quoted phrases "brainstorming", "list answers", "list questions", "idea generation", and "fishing for ideas".*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *The appropriate Help Center page for this is [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), but it's obsolete, having not been updated since the last VTC rule change by Stack Exchange. That's why I'm not linking to it in the body of the post.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *And, by definition, they are opinion-based. But the "opinion-based" VTC reason is a big enough can of worms that it should not be discussed here and I believe there are enough other violations to suit the needs of this proposal.*</sub>

Comment: Are you sure that we can locally change the rules and policies coming from SE?

Comment: @L.Dutch If moderators can modify that paragraph, then the answer is yes. If the only option is a Meta-based policy, then the answer is still yes. Am I answering the correct question? I'm assuming you can modify something about that page because it includes three local links: the Sandbox, the RWQ policy, and the Perfect Question checklist.

Comment: SE policies are decided and enforced by SE. Sort of a constitution. I can rewrite an article of the US constitution, but would that mean that I have amended it?

Comment: Is this a philosophical discussion? Or do we expect SE to complain about either of the proposed modifications? I recall reading some [meta.se] post years ago explaining that SE encouraged communities to set their own policies. Granted, I don't know that they were anticipating setting exceptions to their general rules, but this Stack is pretty hard to use with the strict set SE provides network-wide.

Comment: I don't see a compelling reason to change the rules. Users keep asking discussion/brainstorming questions allover SE, allowing it would just break the rules.

Comment: @L.Dutch You may have seen the comment that preceded this one. If you did, I apologize. I think what I want to do is run a parallel post in [meta.se] that asks if it's permissible for local policies to circumvent SE rules. That would have interesting repercussions for this post (like automatically answering it...).

Comment: [Meta question about whether or not we're allowed to override SE rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385244/395595).

Comment: You’d also need to change less explicit text like this in the tour. *Don't ask about...

Anything not directly related to worldbuilding
Questions that are primarily opinion-based
Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer* By its nature all brainstorming fails that last point.

Comment: @sphennings I don't believe so. The proposed up vote change simply sets an exception to all that for a single question type. I frankly don't think there's a perfect solution. However, I readily admit that clearly setting the down vote policy would be the simplest.

Comment: Unless you want contradictory information in different official parts of the site you will need to be consistent across all text. There are many locations that imply no brainstorming due to it being the antithesis of the sort of question SE wants to support.

Comment: @sphennings I'm not trying to change the rules, I'm trying to clearly create or deny an exception. The idea that we'd need to change everything, everywhere, just to permit brainstorming isn't just overkill... it kinda assumes that we're all idiots. And to make a clear point, if we take all the rules at their word, *every aspect of Worldbuilding that can't be answered on another Stack is off-topic because they break one or more rules.* E.G., magic. If we chase that rabbit much further, we'll find a valid reason to discontinue WB.SE entirely.

Comment: We have plenty of examples of magic questions that do conform to current policy. If someone shows clear worldbuilding purposes they can ask their question here even if it could be answered elsewhere.

Comment: @sphennings Incorrect. From the [tour], "Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based." From [help/dont-ask], constructive questions "insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references." There isn't a magic question on this Stack that conforms to all the rules. Insisting that the rules are what they are invalidates the Stack. (Unless you're asserting that a "worldbuilding purpose" creates an exception to the rules....) You don't really want to open up the VTC:Opinion Based discussion here, do you? *It invalidates almost everything we do.*

Comment: If I ask whether my wizard can shatter bone with his 50 newton telekinetic blast that certainly can be answered with facts and references.

Comment: @sphennings When you remove the irrelevant fantasy nonsense, your question is "can 50 newtons shatter bones?" and that could be asked on [physics.se] or [medicalsciences.se] (probably with better results). I am NOT a believer that a Real World question is magically a Worldbuilding question that can only be asked here simply by claiming it's for a work of fiction. But let's not hijack this discussion. That question can be asked on another stack. I've gotta hit the hay, but you're welcome to find a pure worldbuilding question that doesn't violate at least one SE rule.

Comment: You’ll find that you can trivially strip worldbuilding context from literally every question on this site.

Comment: @JBH I probably would have written two answers to the post titled "I (down/up)vote this policy change". That way we can make a distinction between the quality of the proposal and whether we accept it or not ^^. Right now you're trying to force me into a [false dichotomy of options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma), both of which I disagree (even though I agree with a change!) :p.

Comment: I second @Tortliena, please change the vote counting to the answers, not to the artificial 2 options you have picked. Leave the upvote/downvote to the proposal itself.

Comment: @Tortliena I've tried that before. It doesn't work. If you have a modification, that's a great reason for posting an answer. E.G., "I agree with position X but I think it should be worded Y because...."

Comment: @L.Dutch Ditto what I just told Tort. It doesn't work. It muddies up everything as the two "option answers" become randomly sorted with competing answers, opinions, and alternate discussions. As explained in the post, the post vote is only for the *premise.* Discussion about wordsmithing belongs in the answers.

Comment: @sphennings Every [tag:magic] question on this site cannot have the worldbuilding context trivially stripped from the question. Users on this stack have an *awful* time separating the story from the world. And every [tag:magic] question on this Stack violates the rules about opinion-based answers.

Comment: @L.Dutch Given the discussion concerning [my Meta.se question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385244/395595) and the [Meta.se question for which it was closed as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124911/395595), the answer to your first question, "can we locally change the rules and policies coming from SE?" is a resounding YES.

Comment: @L.Dutch I still hope that the Mods will apply the [tag:featured] tag. There are far too few people who regularly haunt Meta to arrive at what anyone would consider a community consensus.

Comment: @JBH Show me a question where you can't trivially strip worldbuilding context. This  would require rejecting every question on this site. We're fine with answering physics questions here, or math questions, as long as they're clearly about building a fictional world. Other exchanges may also cater to physics questions but they're not as receptive to more fantastical, less grounded in reality questions. You're less likely to get people saying "Yes. And" to the fantastical likely to get called for asking about things that are physically impossible in the real world. That's we do our best work.

Comment: @sphennings Every question using the [tag:magic] tag can't have the worldbuilding context trivially stripped from the question. Unless you think "worldbuilding context" means "back story." Is there still an argument here? There are no questions on this Stack that can't either (a) be moved to another stack or (b) proven off-topic for violating existing SE rules. We've made exceptions like this before, what's the hold up now? Bear in mind *I don't care which path is taken.* My principal complaint is the ambiguity of the existing policy. Unless you also think *that's* a problem.

Comment: @JBH You seem to be creating controversy and ambiguity for yourself. SE's official guidance around POB is "You know it when you see it". This has worked great for years. The problem isn't that everyone has slightly different ideas where to draw the line. The problem is that we have people who ignore policy entirely, and people who get angry when they find out this site has rules that they must follow. It's never "where should I draw the line?" it's always "How dare you close my completely unsuitable question?" or "Why can't use this site for broad opinion based discussions?"

Comment: People demanding why a site billed as a question and answer site, doesn't permit discussions, aren't engaging with this site in good faith. There are plenty of worldbuilding sites on the internet. There are even other worldbuilding Q&A sites. We are the only worldbuilding Stack Exchange, if you don't like the SE model, the one thing that differentiates us from other sites, you don't have to be on a site that was built to follow that model. Every exchange has the same policy and guidelines around broadness and POB, prohibiting brainstorming is trivially derived from that.

Comment: It's sufficient for everyone to know that brainstorming and idea generated are prohibited. Every voting member can use their own assessment of "Is this question brainstorming?" and VTC if yes. We don't need to litigate every edge case. Simply by having a voting body, the questions closed will be the ones that the site as a whole deems to cross the brainstorming threshold. Problems only arise when people don't do the assessment at all.

Comment: @sphennings this post *specifically* states that Opinion-Based is *not* being discussed. Please do not change the subject. It's only being referenced in our comment discussion as evidence that exceptions to SE's rules have been made for other reasons. The ambiguity I'm referring to is the statement in the second-to-last paragraph of [help/on-topic] concerning brainstorming. "... might not be a good place..." is neither a yes, nor a no. Sheesh, Sphen, I thought you'd be all over this proposal like a rash. What's your problem? That I'm not addressing enough of the Stack's issues with this post?

Comment: @JBH This isn't written like a proposal to change the wording in the help center. It's written like you think there's some great controversy about whether brainstorming allowed here. It's clearly not permitted on WB. If you truly just wanted to edit the line you could have written a far shorter post, and asked "Can we improve the wording of the help center by changing X to Y". A far simpler question that is way more meaningful to engage with.

Comment: @sphennings `you think there's some great controversy about whether brainstorming allowed here` *There is...* There are people regularly complaining that we're shutting down brainstorming questions and they're pointing to the existing [help/on-topic] paragraph where it does not say it's prohibited. And the reason I've asked the question the way that I did is that I do not agree that slamming the door is the only option. The Community has a choice, and one of the several big problems with WB.SE right now is that there's a handful of us who aren't allowing the community that choice.

Comment: The same standard of review "I know it when I see it" works every application of community moderation voting. We don't define terms like rude, spam, to broad, primarily oppinion based, or brainstorming. We trust our voting members to make their own determinization and then vote accordingly. Note how the complaint is rarely worded as "I think the line for brainstorming, spam, POB, have been interpreted differently for this post". In practice about how they think they should be able to ask whatever questions they want however they want despite the fundamental design of this site.

Comment: The "controversy" is just people lashing out when their questions get closed. Instead of seeking to understand site policy, they claim that we shouldn't have the policy in the first place. I think the wording in the help center should probably be clearer that brainstorming isn't permitted. Every time someone complains, the exact same answers are given, with the exact same explanations. Show me where there's real controversy. Just another new person coming along, lashing out that this site doesn't work the way they expected it to and trying to change the site instead of learning.

Comment: Yeah, @Sphennings, it is... because they have the right to be represented in a proposal to clarify the policy. What would you do if the community voted to permit brainstorming questions? *Stack Exchange users have the right to change the site.* If that isn't true, then the Santa series is invalid. The ACS is invalid. Most of the Stack is invalid. Deal with it, Sphen. This community allowed exceptions in the past and it's *hypocritical* to assert they don't have the right to make exceptions now.

Comment: Why the obsession to make everything happen on Stack Exchange, why the push to make it a site that it just is not going to be? There are plenty of places elsewhere to have discussions and polls and open-to-all submission posts. Go do it there! Spam is fundamentally impossible to stop and has been ongoing for eight years, doesn't mean that should be allowed either.

Comment: @Nij A friend of mine is quite right... Worldbuilding.SE has lost its heart. That's too bad... especially when the gist of this post is simply clarification to make the moderation process simpler. Why change? Because the Stack has changed. It was once a much happier, livelier, more interesting place. Today, it's just physics-lite that can't gather enough wherewithall to change "maybe..." into a clear "yes" or "no." This Stack is decidedly less than it once was - and the belief that what it is today is what it's always been is heartbreaking.

Comment: @JBH We constantly suggest that they stop complaining and propose a change to site policy. They never do. It is never actually about the policy itself. They want to be able to do whatever they want and are frustrated that to be on this site we expect them to follow the rules.

Comment: @sphennings, All I want is a clear yes or no rather than the muddy and useless maybe the [help/on-topic] currently has. I'm frankly astounded at how much effort you and others are putting in to not getting your way.

Comment: @JBH You're the only one who's claiming that if a question can have it's worldbuilding context removed that it doesn't belong here. Every question on this site can have it's worldbuilding context removed. Since we still have open questions that must not be a realistic standard of review. Since you seem to be the one making up the standard that you're complaining about you can save this site just by relaxing and not attempting to get other people to apply it.

Comment: @JBH If you look what questions get closed, policy discussion on meta, (as opposed to people complaining), or apply common sense to the rest of the text in the help center and tour, the answer is obvious. Brainstorming is not permitted on this site. We used to have a custom close reason for brainstorming. It was called idea generation. It was removed because people felt that we didn't need a custom close reason for something that completely overlapped with  broad and POB. That's the last time this was discussed by the community in earnest. There was no suggestion of not closing the questions.

Comment: @sphennings Shame on you for twisting words. At best, I'm the only one claiming that the strict and ruthless application of rules to the questions on this site would justify its closure. I'm also the only one saying that said argument is irrelevant to the question, which is seeking only to clarify an ambiguity in the [help/on-topic] that you've converted to "prohibition" for your own convenience and preference. Whether or not anything is clear to you is no less relevant to me than claiming that the ambiguity I see is irrelevant to you.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/should-we-rename-idea-generation Perhaps we should re-add the custom close reason, or make the text in the help center clearer. But there never has been any real controversy around brainstorming not being suitable for this site.

Comment: @sphennings `or make the text in the help center clearer` What on earth do you think this post is trying to do?

Comment: @JBH Most of your post is dedicated to presenting the policy itself as unclear, rather than trying changing a single line of text in the help center to better reflect well established site policy. You could have just said "Because brainstorming is not permitted on this site we should remove the word 'maybe' from this line" and I would believe you that you cared about clarifying the text. Given the rest of your post, and everything you've said in the comments, you're clearly wanting to debate the policy itself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this post because it attempts to change fundamentally with how voting works, a [core stack-exchange guideline](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). This creates several issues assessing the post and its answers and makes it broader than it need to be. The post would gain from following a voting model closer to the guidelines.

Comment: Since it's quite an unique case I needed time to think about the potential gain of this method. Sorry, my conclusion is that it's best to rethink the post. Attacking two suggestions at once makes it anyway too broad to make clear community decisions, you're going to have actually 4 kind of votes (aye-aye, aye-nay, nay-aye, nay-nay) + every minor changes. If you do not wish to post answers as proposals -mud is indeed bound to happen ^^-, then perhaps just take the proposal you like the most and make it your vanguard. You can always resort to plan B if it doesn't work ^^.

Comment: Does anyone really think SE is going to come in here and be all like "You guys are too popular, people are enjoying your site too much, and we're shutting you down for violating the letter of our law, which we made with other sites in mind." I'm pretty sure as long as Worldbuilding isn't going off the rails and turning into 4chan, they aren't going to mind if we allow brainstorming or questions that are not precisely one question. SE's statements are pretty friendly and permissible. Lots of "should" and "may", not a lot of of "never" or "can't".

Comment: My two cents... WB is a forever Q&A, there are questions and answers. SE has common rules and quality expectations, but I keep wondering what *actual* restrictions SE would put on WB's local rules, in daily practice ? It would be a complicated and time-consuming checkup. Reviewing all the rules WB has invented.. and I wonder if there's ANY Stackexchange place with rules as numerous and difficult as ours and getting debated so often ?

Answer (score 4):

I am going to quote Shog's answer to the Meta question which says Communities can change SE rules and policies:

> ### We're still not building a [Ute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ute_%28vehicle%29)
>
> Obviously there are some invariables - **we’re building Q&A sites here, not discussion forums or service directories**; no matter how much you might want [Aww.SE](http://www.reddit.com/r/aww/), we're [*just not building a truck here*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/), and we're not gonna let you [use our shoes to drive nails](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx). That's why, even on sites with elected moderators, we'll occasionally step in to remind folks what the purpose of these sites are, and try to refocus them on that goal.

Comment: Is this an answer to my question? I want to see a "maybe..." changed to a clear "yes" or "no." How is this post relevant to the question?

Comment: @JBH blame the OP for having engineered a question which cannot be upvoted/downvoted for its merit and that is being drowned into an endless chain of comments

Comment: Then push the comment chain into chat and feature the question so that more than a few loudmouths can see it. I entirely disagree that the question can't be voted on for its merit. I've tried pushing the text modifications into answers *and it doesn't work.* The question may be voluminous, *but it's clear.* I'm shocked that Sphennings isn't *dancing* over the chance to get the clarification he'd prefer. Do you actually believe there's a significant improvement over the wording for the down vote?

Comment: @JBH, as far as I have been on SE, upvote = question is useful and clear, downvote = question is not useful and unclear. You are purposely altering this fundamental mechanism, assuming that whoever votes will dive into reading the wall of text to find what you assigned as value to the up and downvote.

Comment: So the last 13 hours have been nothing more than people complaining that they don't like how I wrote the question? That's rich, since one of Sphenning's arguments is that people should be capable of looking past the terrible wording in the [help/on-topic] and see what was meant. Bit of a double standard, there.

Comment: Look, Dutch, do us all a favor. Since you're not willing to make this post visible to the general community on Main, delete this entire post (since your answer disallows me from doing it), then go change the [help/on-topic] to clearly state that brainstorming is prohibited. Problem solved, fuss over.

Comment: @JBH You could always edit the post. Remove the confusing language about upvotes, and downvotes. Either propose a single course of action. Or create two answers, each one taking a single side. That would result in a post much easier for the community to engage with meaningfully. It should be pretty quick to cut out the pro and con arguments into separate answers if you wanted to clean it up quick.

Comment: @sphennings As the post stands, the vote is to edit the [help/on-topic] to clearly state that brainstorming is prohibited. I'm content with that resolution.

Comment: @JBH Or people used downvotes for their intended purpose and said that they find your post doesn't show research, is unclear, or not useful. We have no way of distinguishing between the two options.

Comment: @JBH You have 2 cells which can be filled with at least 4 possible different meanings. It's very unreasonable to induce what any of people's vote mean, if they followed you or the widely accepted community guidelines. I myself can only tell I respected your choice, even if it means I cannot vote nor answer.

Comment: @JBH I agree, we should split the post into multiple posts and vote. I believe and support allowing people to ask open-ended questions, because as far as my short experience on this site has gone, every question I've seen flagged as open ended or requesting peoples opinions have been to positive effect. The core purpose of moderation is, first and foremost, maintaining and improving the thing being moderated. (*continues*)

Comment: If our objective is to **maintain and improve** the site, is allowing these opinion and idea-fishing questions **damaging** to the site, or **improving it**. My stance is clear, but for everyone here, I think explaining why you vote in a given direction will, for one, end debate and ambiguity, and secondly, establish a **why** so no debate on this topic would need to ensue in the future.

Comment: And for clarification, by **maintain**, I am referring to removing **damaging** content or media from the site, such as things that break the rules, which are inherently damaging in one form or another.

Comment: My apologies for my language skills, I am not usually very good at phrasing my arguments... but I hope you understand roughly what I mean.

Comment: An addendum I would like to add is, if we **were** to disallow this kind of content on our site, where would you post such questions? Where would you find a large community that specializes in what we do, with the simple difference of allowing such open ended questions (I use that as a generalization for what the OP has outlined I.E. idea-fishing and such the like)

Comment: It's very late and I spent too long redacting my answer, I will see what happens tomorrow.

Comment: @L.Dutch If exchanging ideas and creativity so that story creators, whether they be video game makers or short story writers, can improve each-others work, wouldn't we simply be driving people **away** from using the **world building** stack? If it is so pivotal to the group of people this stack built for, then why are we making it difficult or flat out forcing people away because of said piece of policy?

Comment: It seems like you haven't understood the answer you're commenting in. *"where would you post such questions?"* - somewhere that is **not here**. Good for you for wanting everyone to be helped in the one place, but that's just not going to happen, it's not possible to do so. The only reason SE works so well is because it does not allow everything everywhere. Imagine walking into a burger shop and saying they should make you a pizza, what, just because they both involve some kind of bread holding some ingredients? That's what your idea boils down to, and it has all the same problems. @SamKitsune

Comment: @Nij "everything everywhere" is a far cry from asking for suggestions or fishing for ideas. For second, your argument is an analogy, and one that hinges on the above. If you have a properly structured argument, then post it as an answer.

Comment: It just makes it so people can ask questions that don't have a 'best' answer. For example, if I were to ask how society might react with the introduction of a large population of animal human hybrids, which is something I actually want answered, it would be disallowed because it is asking for an opinion, even if it is about building a plausible and believable world for a story.

Comment: Even with said rule, I could easily post (and in fact have (sort of)) those kinds of questions and get genuinely good answers. I have yet to see first or second hand a case were asking for opinions has created situations that are undesirable. We are simply trying to adhere to rules designed for a different kind of community.

Comment: If we are going to unyieldingly abide by rules that are not meant for a community this stack is built for, then **a world-building *stack exchange* should not exist in the first place**

Comment: Clarification for the sleuth that wants to try for formulate a counterargument to my last statement by manipulating the context of my words. What I mean by what I said is that **a world-building section doesn't belong in the stack exchange.** It just doesn't work. JBH makes this crystal clear, and an extension of this is that if we try to force this stack to conform with the stack exchange model, then we shouldn't even be marketing it as a tool for world-builders. (authors, game devs, any creative endeavor, really.)

Comment: @Nij and that was only half of my argument, the other half being, why? Why do we vote the direction we vote? I want to see a real explanation as to why it damages the community, or why it does not.

Comment: **IF** these questions were to be allowed, what would change? Why would they change? Would they change for the worst? Would they change for the better? I stand behind JBH because I share his opinion. For example, I asked about a dyson swarm in my last post. I wanted to know if and how could a bomb be built to destroy one. It is inherently an open ended question because I want to how to make one work in my fictional world.

Comment: One would have to understand what exactly you're trying to say, to avoid "manipulating" your words. Throwing in arbitrary emphasis makes it impossible to figure out what the emphasis is meant to be on. You're writing multiple comments to expound on a point, suggests it is not coherent enough to be relevant here.

Comment: But I simply rephrased the question so that it could abide by the rules and OP would stop nagging me about it, because he did, and I got kind of pissed because I though he was mini-modding, but he was not. I rephrased the question and only hoped that people would respond with the yes/no answer and (not necessarily, but usually) give an alternative that would work better, describing their idea of how to destroy said swarm with a bunch of steel rods. Go check for yourself, it was quite ingenious.

Comment: The point is that I still, in the end, sidestepped the rules, asking a yes/no question but still got the answers I would have gotten otherwise. Fishing for others ideas that would fit in with the problem.

Comment: So in other words, you asked a question in a way that doesn't work here, and it could be reformulated into a question that does work here, and everything turned out fine with the system exactly as it is. And you think that justifies changing the system because you could interpret that as the system not working? Well, good luck with that.

Comment: Even if explicitly fishing for ideas is disallowed, it still doesn't stop me from doing what I did above with that post. I got ideas from others. And I didn't break the rules, because I didn't ask for them, they were simply given.

Comment: @Nij My point is that I used a **workaround**, it's dirty (metaphorically) and we can make it a lot simpler for new people. It's a clean solution that no one has shown to be damaging. I am completely open to listen to a counterargument as to why it would be worse for the community.